# Notepad++ Regex: delete lines that are identical between start and defined string and clip after said string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to remove lines that are identical from start until a defined string within the line and clip everything after that string.

Example lines:

```
http://waterfountain.common.com/12443
http://waterfountain.common.com/243
http://waterfountain.common.com/243
http://glass.common.com/clear
http://glass.common.com/clear
http://1room.common.com/closet/empty
```

In this case, I'd like to compare everything from linestart to "common.com", delete all duplicates and additionally clip everything after the "common.com" or the "/".

Desired endresult would look like: (with or without "/" at the end)

```
http://waterfountain.common.com/
http://glass.common.com/
```

I found partial solutions, but I don't know how to modify/combine them to my needs.

For example delete lines that are completely identical:

```
^(.*?)$\s+?^(?=.*^\1$)
```

Edit:
I tried the solution of "The fourth bird" and while it does work for the case I mentioned, some testing showed that there are cases where it fails. (Cases which I forgot to mention.)

It is possible that a number appears after the initial "//", e.g.

```
http://2eyes.common.com/
```

It's also possible that there are letters after the third "/", e.g.

```
http://snow.common.com/first/
```

Comment: I hope you are looking for [THIS](https://superuser.com/questions/1387677/mark-or-remove-partly-duplicate-lines-in-notepad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your current example data, you might use a capturing group to capture right before the forward slash and a digit as the defined string.

Then match from that point until the end of the string and repeat the matching using a backreference to group 1.

```
^(https?://[^/\n]+)/.*(?:\R\1.*)*
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(https?://[^/\n]+)` Group 1, capture http:// with optional s before first encountered forward slash
- `/.*` Match forward slash followed by any char except a newline 0+ times
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\R\1.*` Match any unicode newline sequence, back reference to group 1 and the rest of the string
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times

In the replacement using the first capturing group `$1`.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nc0Ypx/1/)

Result

```
http://waterfountain.common.com
http://glass.common.com
```

Comment: Thank you. After some testing I noticed that this doesn't catch some cases which I failed to specify.
It is possible that a number appears after the //, e.g. http://2eyes.common.com .
It's also possible that there are letters after the third /, e.g. https://snow.common.com/first

Comment: @Winter Why not add them to your question?

Comment: You are correct, this makes it more clear. I edited the initial question.

Comment: @Winter Do the lines always start with `http://`? In that case you could use `^(https?://[^/\n]+)/.*(?:\R\1.*)*` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nc0Ypx/1)

Comment: @Winter I have updated my answer using this last pattern.

Comment: It's either http:// or https://. I just tried your solution and it works. Thank you.